# Programmatically add fixed footer in JqueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, footer

i try to add footer in my jquery mobile page programmatically.

Here is my code to add html markup for footer and trigger the "create" function of jquerymobile again to populate the style for the footer.

```
            menu += '<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="menu" data-theme="a">';
            menu +=     '<div data-role="navbar">';
            menu +=         '<ul>';
            menu +=             '<li><a href="'+GLOBAL.APP_ROOT+'simulator/list1">List1</a></li>';
            menu +=             '<li><a href="'+GLOBAL.APP_ROOT+'simulator/list2">List1</a></li>';
            menu +=             '<li><a href="'+GLOBAL.APP_ROOT+'simulator/list3">List3</a></li>';
            menu +=         '</ul>';
            menu +=     '</div>';
            menu += '</div>';
            $('#pHome').append(menu).trigger('create');
```

My problem is, the footer doesn't appear at the bottom of the page, it appears right after the content div. I think that i have to update the position of the footer div manually but don't know how to do that. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$.mobile.fixedToolbars.show();` after this line `$('#pHome').append(menu).trigger('create');`.This should force jquery mobile to recalculate the position of the fixed toolbar and show it.That should keep the footer at the bottom.